# Model of light distribution along radius

Tags: visible-light, dirac-delta-distributions

I measured the light intensity of Xe lamp along the radius at different points. By using polyfit function, I have found the function of light distribution along the radius. [image: Light distribution along the radius]

I want to model the light distribution (intensity) along the radius by using the polynomial function which is similar like the image I attached which I obtained from [Model radiated power from an LED](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585212/model-radiated-power-from-an-led). However, I want the range of both axes starting from -3.6 to 3.6. May I know how I proceed?
[image: Source:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585212/model-radiated-power-from-an-led]

Comment: This is obviously a question of how you have generated the plot. You need to give more details about that. This is not really a physics question though and might be more appropriate in relevant coding language stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply